# WebView ignores attributes weight and height

Tags: java, android, html, webview, jsoup

I'm trying to load html document to WebView via JSoup. Document has images:

```
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-21038" src="http://example.com/1.jpg" alt="test" width="1920" height="1080">

<img class="wp-image-21035 size-full" src="http://example.com/2.jpg" alt="test 2" width="1920" height="1080">

<img class="size-full wp-image-21036" src="http://example.com/1.jpg" alt="test 3" width="1920" height="1080">

<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-21037" src="http://example.com/1.jpg" alt="test 4" width="1920" height="1080">
```

I change `width="1920" height="1080"` to `width="100%" height="auto"` this way:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/test").get();
                entryContent = doc.select("#content .entry-content");

                for( Element element : entryContent.select("img")) {
                    element.attr("width", "100%");
                    element.attr("height", "auto");
                    System.out.println(element);
                }
```

logcat shows that new attributes applied to all four images

```
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-21038" src="http://example.com/1.jpg" alt="test" width="100%" height="auto">

<img class="wp-image-21035 size-full" src="http://example.com/2.jpg" alt="test 2" width="100%" height="auto">

<img class="size-full wp-image-21036" src="http://example.com/1.jpg" alt="test 3" width="100%" height="auto">

<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-21037" src="http://example.com/1.jpg" alt="test 4" width="100%" height="auto">
```

But WebView ignores new attributes for second and third image. First image and the last one shows correct. Where can be problem?

Comment: Do you have a typo in the second `img` element looks like `example.con` should that be `example.com`?

Comment: @NoahHerron yes, it's a typo.

Comment: the ```aligncenter``` class is only present for the first and last ```<img>```. maybe that class is needed for the full width display?